# Insert multiple rows into database using the results of another query

Tags: mysql

I want to insert multiple rows into my table using the output of another query.

My insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO group_messages (group_message_text,group_message_group_id,group_message_user_id)
VALUES ('Rounded ended! Hit the standings button in the top right corner to check your score.','$group_id','0')
```

Here `$group_id` will need to get filled with however many `group_ids` get returned from this query:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM groups
```

The second query now returns `3 group_ids: 1, 2, 3`

This should thus lead to something like:

```
INSERT INTO group_messages (group_message_text,group_message_group_id,group_message_user_id)
VALUES ('Rounded ended! Hit the standings button in the top right corner to check your score.','1','0'), ('Rounded ended! Hit the standings button in the top right corner to check your score.','2','0'), ('Rounded ended! Hit the standings button in the top right corner to check your score.','3','0')
```

Comment: You can use insert select command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
INSERT INTO group_messages 
(group_message_text,group_message_group_id,group_message_user_id)
select "Rounded ended! Hit the standings button in the top right corner to 
check your score.",group_id,0 FROM groups
```

Comment: Please mark it as right answer if it work for you thanks